# Set theory notation for intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I've started reading [Probability by Blikzstein and Wang](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Probability-Chapman-Statistical-Science/dp/1466575573) and run into the following formula:

$B = \bigcap_{j=1}^{10} A_{j}$

I wasn't able to find a definition of the notation in the book, or on Wikipedia:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_notation
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory

I think I can guess what the notation means, but I was hoping to find a formal definition.

I have seen a similar question here: [Set Theory Notation Crises](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396116/set-theory-notation-crises), however that question does not have the digits above the intersection symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In set theory given a class term $X$ its intersection is defined as
$$
\bigcap X := \{x \mid \forall y \in X, x \in y\}.
$$
Now, note that we can equivalently write
$$
\bigcap_{j = 1}^{10} A_j = \bigcap \{A_j \mid \forall j \in \{1, \ldots, 10\}\}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\bigcap_{j = 1}^{10} A_j = \{x \mid \forall j \in \{1, \ldots, 10\}, x \in A_j\}.
$$
Check out 'Introduction to set theory' by Hrbacek and Jech for further info.

Comment: There's a typo, the quanter has nothing to do here :
$\bigcap_{j = 1}^{10} A_j := \bigcap \{A_j \mid  j \in \{1, \ldots, 10\}\}.$

Answer (score 3):

It's a short-hand notation for $B= A_1\cap A_2\cap \ldots \cap A_{10}$.